# Taking the related data by count in Asp.net core 5.0

Tags: asp.net, database, performance, linq, asp.net-core-5.0

My query works so well but there is a small problem about what data im getting.

```
      public IEnumerable<MainCategory> IsFeaturedMainCategoriesRelatedCat(int count)
        {
            return TradeTurkDBContext.MainCategories
                .Where(x => x.MainCategoryIsFeatured == true)
                .Include(x => x.Category)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Products)
                .AsNoTracking().ToList().GetRange(0, count);
        }
```

in that query, im getting the all `Category` data's from my database. I wanna take 5 `MainCategory` , i wanna take 5 `Category`  and all `Products` which is related a `Category` .
All i can do is now getting 5 `MainCategory` and gettin all  `Category` data's from my database.

There is a One-To-Many relationship between `MainCategory` and `Category` ,`Category` and `Products` .

**Thanks for any suggestion!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need feature that `Include` can limit loaded records, introduced in EF Core 5:

```cs
public IEnumerable<MainCategory> IsFeaturedMainCategoriesRelatedCat(int count)
{
    return TradeTurkDBContext.MainCategories
        .Where(x => x.MainCategoryIsFeatured == true)
        .Include(x => x.Category.Take(count))
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Products)
        .Take(count)
        .AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,its works so well. i got like 120 ```Category``` in my project,there is a big difference about time with your answer.  Thanks again!